# Date regular expression gives error

Tags: php, regex, date, format

I have been working on my date regular expression all day...
I want a date format to be YYYY-MM-DD.

```
$date_regex ='^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$';

if (preg_match($date_regex, $dateString)) {
        echo "good format";
    }
```

keeps giving me error

> preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in test.php on line 19

Anyone help?? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your regular expression in a pair of delimiting characters. Also, you need to escape the dashes in your character classes using `\`.

Try this (I'm using `#` as a delimiter):

```
$date_regex ='#^(19|20)\d\d[\- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$#';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the /s otherwise the regex thinks you are limiting it with the ^

```
'/^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/'
```

Regards

Comment: AAh BoltClock beat me to it, and gave a better answer to boot :p

Comment: If you use `/` you need to escape the other `/`s in the regex so PHP doesn't end the regex prematurely. Specifically in the character classes (escape the dash too): [\- \/.]

Comment: also tried to bold the relevant /s but the code bit didnt pick them up :s

Comment: Yep same in Perl, very used to writing \/ in Regexes,